# Cannot connect to compose.io hosted rethinkdb with clojure

Tags: clojure, rethinkdb, compose-db

I'm using the clojure rethinkdb library https://github.com/apa512/clj-rethinkdb - here's my connection snippet:

```
(ns rethink.core
  (:require
    [environ.core]
    [cheshire.core :as json]
    [org.httpkit.client :as http]
    [rethinkdb.query :as r]))

(defn rethink-connect
  []
  (r/connect  :host     (environ.core/env :rethinkdb-host)
              :port     (environ.core/env :rethinkdb-port)
              :db       (environ.core/env :rethinkdb-db)
              :auth-key (environ.core/env :rethinkdb-auth)))

(defn record-event!
  [event collection]
  (let [r  (with-open [conn (rethink-connect)]
              (-> (r/table collection)
                  (r/insert [event])
                  (r/run conn)))]))
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Error connecting to RethinkDB database
                      core.clj:4617 clojure.core/ex-info
                      core.clj:4617 clojure.core/ex-info
                        core.clj:88 rethinkdb.core/connect
                        core.clj:43 rethinkdb.core/connect
                    RestFn.java:619 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
                        core.clj:10 rethink.core/rethink-connect
                         core.clj:8 rethink.core/rethink-connect
                        core.clj:17 rethink.core/record-event!
                        core.clj:15 rethink.core/record-event!
                        core.clj:23 webhook.core/record-event!
                        core.clj:21 webhook.core/record-event!
                     handler.clj:11 webhook.handler/webhook-post
                      handler.clj:8 webhook.handler/webhook-post
                      handler.clj:9 app.handler/fn
                      handler.clj:9 app.handler/fn
                       core.clj:135 compojure.core/make-route[fn]
                       core.clj:122 compojure.core/wrap-route-middleware[fn]
                       core.clj:126 compojure.core/wrap-route-info[fn]
                        core.clj:45 compojure.core/if-route[fn]
                        core.clj:27 compojure.core/if-method[fn]
                       core.clj:151 compojure.core/routing[fn]
                      core.clj:2592 clojure.core/some
                      core.clj:2583 clojure.core/some
                       core.clj:151 compojure.core/routing
                       core.clj:148 compojure.core/routing
                    RestFn.java:139 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
                       core.clj:648 clojure.core/apply
                       core.clj:641 clojure.core/apply
                       core.clj:156 compojure.core/routes[fn]
              keyword_params.clj:35 ring.middleware.keyword-params/wrap-keyword-params[fn]
                      params.clj:64 ring.middleware.params/wrap-params[fn]
          absolute_redirects.clj:38 ring.middleware.absolute-redirects/wrap-absolute-redirects[fn]
                content_type.clj:30 ring.middleware.content-type/wrap-content-type[fn]
             default_charset.clj:26 ring.middleware.default-charset/wrap-default-charset[fn]
                not_modified.clj:52 ring.middleware.not-modified/wrap-not-modified[fn]
                       Var.java:379 clojure.lang.Var.invoke
                      reload.clj:22 ring.middleware.reload/wrap-reload[fn]
                  stacktrace.clj:23 ring.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace-log[fn]
                  stacktrace.clj:86 ring.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace-web[fn]
                       jetty.clj:20 ring.adapter.jetty/proxy-handler[fn]
                   (Unknown Source) ring.adapter.jetty.proxy$org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler$ff19274a.handle
            HandlerWrapper.java:116 org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle
                    Server.java:369 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle
    AbstractHttpConnection.java:486 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest
    AbstractHttpConnection.java:944 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content
   AbstractHttpConnection.java:1005 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content
                HttpParser.java:865 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext
                HttpParser.java:240 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable
        AsyncHttpConnection.java:82 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle
     SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668 org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle
      SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52 org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run
          QueuedThreadPool.java:608 org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob
          QueuedThreadPool.java:543 org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run
                    Thread.java:745 java.lang.Thread.run
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Character
                       RT.java:1177 clojure.lang.RT.intCast
                        tcp.clj:156 aleph.tcp/client
                        tcp.clj:126 aleph.tcp/client
                        core.clj:61 rethinkdb.core/connect
```

I'm getting the host "aws-us-xxx-1-portal.xxx.xxxx.com", port "15731", db "dev" and auth-key from my compose.io rethinkdb instance. The auth-key is the admin password taken from authentication credential provided by compose.io interface. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I needed to use a `:ca-cert` parameter as well, with the certificate being provided from the compose.io web interface.